# how to set rectangular shaped bitmap to rounded images

Tags: android

I am using this function to get rounded images and setting to imageview its working fine for square shaped bitmaps but for rectangular shaped bitmaps its not making rounded images and shapes are uneven

```
   public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),                               Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    final RectF rectF = new RectF(10, 10,150,150);
    final float roundPx = pixels;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like similar to your code. but it is working for square and rectangle shaped Bitmaps. try this...

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int cornerRadius) {

        if (bitmap == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (cornerRadius < 0) {
            cornerRadius = 0;
        }
        // Create plain bitmap
        Bitmap canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
        canvas.drawARGB(0,0,0,0);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, paint);

        final int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        final int height = bitmap.getHeight();

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return canvasBitmap;
    }
```

do this operation in non UI thread

Comment: can you post your sample Bitmap in any image hosting sites and give that link to me...

Answer (score 0):

RoundedImageView .java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {


public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

if (drawable == null) {
    return;
}

if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
    return; 
}
Bitmap b =  ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap() ;
Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();


Bitmap roundBitmap =  getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0,0, null);
}

public Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
Bitmap sbmp;
if(bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
    sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
else
    sbmp = bmp;
Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(),
        sbmp.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

final int color = 0xffa19774;
final Paint paint = new Paint();
final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
paint.setDither(true);
canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f,
        sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.1f, paint);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);


        return output;
}

}
```

And call the Bitmap by

```
imgview.setImageBitmap(new RoundedImageView(getApplicationContext()).getCroppedBitmap(PassedImage, 100));
```

Comment: so you are performing huge Bitmap operations in onDraw() method. don't do that... it's not at all the way to create an Object in onDraw() method.